# Tracking keyword analytics for a custom web search engine while user is in icognito mode or clears cache and cookies

Tags: analytics

Suppose I'm building a custom web search engine, would I be able to provide the websites using the search engine with basic keyword analytics (i.e. which keywords result in impressions and click-throughs for their webpages) even if the web users are browsing using incognito mode or after clearing cache and cookies?

If so, what is the technical method used to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The incognito mode means that a browser doesn't save cookies, temporary internet files or your browsing history. Even if you go “incognito”, the websites will still collect or share information about you, for example, Google and other search engines know our location and a language of a browser we use in the incognito mode. So, the incognito mode keeps your browser from storing information about you, but it doesn’t mean that you’re completely isolated from other sites you are browsing in the incognito mode including their “anonymous” cookies. Hence, the incognito mode doesn't really change the tracking approach much and any custom Google-like search engine will work for you.